# JavaScript: How can I reduce first name to an initial in just one line?

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking for a single line replacement for this block of code:

```
function convertFirstNameToInitial(sFullName) {
    sFullName = sFullName.split(" ");
    sFullName[0] = sFullName[0].substr(0, 1) + ".";
    return sFullName.join(" ");
}
```

That does this:

`George Washington` becomes `G. Washington`.

`Carice van Houten` becomes `C. van Houten`

`Henry De la Beche` becomes `H. De la Beche`

And so on...

You ask why? Because I feel there *must* be an easier way.

P.S: Sorry if I posted a duplicate question.

Comment: function is clear and easy to understand, I think it is bad idea to change it ^^ if you will write something like `sFullName.split(" ").map((n, i) => i === 0 ? n.substr(0, 1) + "." : n).join(" ");` - it will 'blow your mind' in 2 months

Comment: @AndrewEvt: I deleted that answer for a reason... It's a pretty horrible approach...

Comment: @Andrew Evt, sure I could.. It's just that I was looking to manipulate my view in the view itself and not having to add additional lines of code in the controller and I thought what better way than getting the result in one single line?

Comment: than use `Regexp`, as in @Matt Burland answer - its the 'cleanest' way here

Comment: I'd just replace 'sFullName[0].substr(0, 1)' with 'sFullName[0].charAt(0)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Basic* cheap string manipulation can do this:

```
name = name[0].toUpperCase() + "." + name.substring(name.indexOf(" "));
```

Comment: Although I was inclined to use the `RegExp` approach in Matt Burland's answer yet this one fitted just perfectly in my requirement. Thanks Alex. K.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a good place to use some Regexfoo:

```js
regex = /([A-Z])\w+ (\w+)/
console.log("George Washington".replace(regex, "$1. $2"));
console.log("Carice van Houten".replace(regex, "$1. $2"));
```

Comment: What if there is accidentally a case where the first letter is not a capital?

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush: So what if a string that doesn't match the pattern doesn't match the pattern?

Comment: Maybe replace the `[A-Z]` with `[A-z]`

Comment: Just saying, the OP did not specify that every first name was going to be capitalized by default (could be user input error).

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush: The OP didn't say they would be written in Arabic either, but don't see the point of inventing requirements that *weren't in the question*

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush Why would that case have to be an "accident"? A "name" could be one or more of any characters or symbols.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/af/Prince_logo.svg/19px-Prince_logo.svg.png, "e e cummings", "k.d. lang"

Comment: @guest271314 My name also begins with a lower case letter, but I was not going to make a deal of it. I was just saying the answer would work, but also would break on corner cases.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush It is an interesting study. Neither arabic nor english has anything to do with whether or not a "name" begins with a character considered lower case. Users who upvoted comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026045/javascript-how-can-i-reduce-first-name-to-an-initial-in-just-one-line/44026161?noredirect=1#comment75079486_44026161 should remember their vote at present Question at other Answers which strictly meet requirement described at Question; and refrain from commenting, i.e.g,; "what about x, y, z case" at similar questions and answers where edge cases may exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.indexOf()`

```js
var abbr = str => str[0] + "." + str.slice(str.indexOf(" "));

console.log(
  abbr("George Washington")
, abbr("Carice van Houten")
, abbr("Henry De la Beche")
);
```

Comment: May I suggest not re-declaring `str`? Just pass the string directly, don't bother using that variable...

Comment: @Cerbrus That is only to demonstrate approach at stacksnippets.

Comment: ... I don't really see why you'd need the `str` variable for that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Should not be an issue to demonstrate approach. Updated nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex here

```js
var names = [
  'George Washington',

  'Carice van Houten',

  'Henry De la Beche'
];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  console.log(names[i].replace(/^(\w)\w+/, '$1.'));
}
```